# Python if statement to find Armstrong Numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, list

```
n = int(input("" ""))
l = []
for i in  range(n):
    a = int(input())
    l.append(a)
    s=0
for i in l:
    temp = i

    while temp>0:
        d = temp % 10
        s += d**3
        temp //= 10
    if n == s:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

I am trying to print 'yes' if the number is an Armstrong number and 'no' if not. But the code only runs the `else` part. The `if` part is not executing, please help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? What have you tried?

Comment: i tried but still getting single output as 'no' always

Comment: I guess `s` should be initialized to 0 for each `i`

Comment: tried doing that didn't work

Comment: You need to be patient and understand yourself what should be the flow. Use print statements and verify if that was what you were expecting at that line of code. This way you can debug and fix your code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `if n == s:` to `if i == s:` since `i` is the number to test, and `n` is how many number you are testing.

And as Damien said, `s` should be initialized to 0 for each `i`

```
n = int(input("" ""))
l = []
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    l.append(a)
for i in l:
    s=0
    temp = i

    while temp>0:
        d = temp % 10
        s += d**3
        temp //= 10
    if i == s:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Test part :

```
1 # input, n = how many numbers i to test
1 # input, i = number to test
yes # output
```

Comment: but still prints only else part

Comment: cf my "Test part" : if your number is an Armstrong number like 0, 1, 153... then it will outputs "yes"